# How to prove that $\{1/n\}\cup \{0\}$ is compact by open covers?

Tags: analysis, compactness

Given any open cover of the set I need to find a finite subcover, how can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

Some member of the open cover covers $0$.  How many points in the set does that one open set fail to cover?

Comment: It may be finite or infinite depending on the given cover.

Comment: @DIEGORAMOS:  Can it be infinite?

Comment: No. You're Right I get it